# How should I go about learning more diverse fields of mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

I am a beginning PhD student and the topic of my thesis is somewhere between real analysis, functional analysis and theoretical numerics. However, I am really curious about many (or rather most) fields of mathematics. If possible, I'd like to learn everything about mathematics, but of course I know that that's completely impossible.

How should I go about learning more about other fields of mathmatics that are not related to my thesis? I basically see two different ways how to approach this, although I am open to other ways I might have missed. Suppose I spend $n$ hours each day doing mathematics by myself. Is it better to spend those $n$ hours completely on working on my thesis, or to spend $n-k$ hours on my thesis and $k$ hours on learning some other topic, like algebra, topology, etc.? Suppose the latter option is preferable, what is an optimal value of $k$?

The reason why I am hesitating to spend time learning other topics is that I sometimes feel like wasting time, as I never know if I can ever apply this knowledge, or if I can even remember it when I could apply it. On the other hand, I don't think I will have more time later on in my career, so if I don't spend time now with other topics, I might never get a real chance to do so later again (except for retirement).

The same question for things that are related to mathematics but not mathematics themselves. For example, I am very interested in theoretical physics and AI.

Comment: You should indicate which country you are in because Ph.D. programs vary quite a bit. For example, in the U.S. one typically spends a couple of years taking a relatively diverse range of graduate courses before beginning research. That said, my feeling is that once you're at the point that you are working on research for your thesis, then you shouldn't be spending any time on something else (except required TA work, attending related seminars, etc.). In later years you'll likely have the opportunity to learn other things by teaching classes, working on problems with colleagues, etc.

Comment: I am doing my Ph.D. in Austria (Europe). Here, we don't have to take any graduate courses anymore.

Comment: The optimal value of $k$ varies depending on context. Sometimes you get stuck or exhausted working on your PhD, so then you could turn to something else for a while to take your mind off of things. Also, rather than picking other topics randomly it is more productive to go off on a tangent from something that comes up in your main work, or look into things that people you have access to (professors or other students) specialize in. That way you get somebody to talk to about it. And, of course, you should start by discussing such explorations with your thesis advisor.